# Google Chrome not playing mp4 files

Tags: google-chrome, mp4

Videos stopped after 1 frame, I have tried local mp4 files, vimeo html5 videos and coursera videos and they all stopped after one frame and stopped loading. My system is 64-bit Windows 8, anyone have similar problem or could someone tell what is wrong with Chrome? Version 23 works perfectly with mp4s but version 24 has this problem. And it can perfectly play webm files, is Google dropping h.264 support for Chrome now as promised? Why'd they still say that "Your browser support h.264" on YouTube? I have "refreshed" the operating system but it's the same. Version 24.0.1312.52 m

Comment: Hav you changed something under **chrome://flags** ?

Comment: No. I have not changed anything in chrome:flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the hardware acceleration issue, try disabling GPU acceleration with the Chrome flags.

Comment: Enable "Disable hardware-accelerated video decode" works. Could expect a bug fix. Chromium issue 164053